# How to set html input tag width "fit-content" in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input tag in my HTML page as following.

I want to make an input tag width to fit the content and minimum width.
So I wrote CSS as follows.

```css
.number-input {
  width: fit-content;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-input">
  <input type="text" value="200001230001003002" class="number-input">
  <button class="save"></button>
</div>
```

Is it possible to adjust CSS so the input will fit the text width?

I searched already, but the answers use the javascript function.

Please anyone help.

Comment: you should use javascript or  you can use <span> instead of input tag.

Comment: You will have to use javascript, or you could use a editable div, instead of the input field.
You cannot make a <input> fit it's content.

Comment: You can try something like this <div contenteditable="true" class="number-input" style="display: inline"></div> instead of input.

Comment: I posted answer without javascript, but I think the best solution is to use javascript.

Comment: Thank you @Raeesh Alam, contenteditable is working in my chrome. Btw, is it possible to input only number?

Comment: @Deniel Then you need to play with *JavaScript* for number only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this.
I posted two solution with span and data-*.

html

```
    <p>solution with span <span class="number-input" role="textbox" contenteditable>200001230001003002</span></p>
    
    <p>Solution with data-*<label class="input-sizer" data-value="200001230001003002">
        <input class="number-input1" type="text" oninput="this.parentNode.dataset.value = this.value" size="1" value="200001230001003002">
    </label></p>
    <button class="save"></button>
```

-css

```
.number-input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

.number-input1{
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.input-sizer {
  display: inline-grid;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}  

.input-sizer::after 
{
    content: attr(data-value) "  ";
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
}
```

Comment: best solution is to use javascript

Comment: Thank you @George, Is it possible to input only number if i use contenteditable?

Comment: if you want to input only number in contenteditable, i think you use javascript. what about second solution(data-value)?

Answer (score 6):

This is a great time to use that rarely used unit of `ch` which is relative to the width of the "0" (zero) of the current font and font sized used!  Then use JS to make the width equal to the length of the input in `ch` I've done this in 2 places, once when it loads, and then subsequently on the `onkeypress` so that it will expand when edited.  Take a look here:

```css
.number-input {
    width: fit-content;
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-input">
    <input type="text" id="mytxt" onkeypress="this.style.width = (this.value.length) + 'ch';" value="200001230001003002" class="number-input" onload="myFunction()">
    <button onload="myFunction()" class="save"></button>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mytxt").style.width = (mytxt.value.length) + 'ch';
}

window.onload = myFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting, shame it only works properly with mono-spaced fonts.

Answer (score -3):

try this one

```css
.number-input {
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="price-input">
  <input type="text" value="200001230001003002" class="number-input">
  <button>Click it</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: width="46" using in chrome   check for chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content